# Confusion around case statements in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can somebody help me with the difference between the below two statements. Do both of them give me the same  result?

```
SELECT    
      COUNT( CASE WHEN DischargeDate > '20130609' and DischargeDate < '20140101' THEN Encounter END) as '1case'
      COUNT( CASE WHEN DischargeDate > '20130509' and DischargeDate < '20131201' THEN Encounter END) as '2case'
      COUNT( CASE WHEN DischargeDate > '20130409' and DischargeDate < '20131101' THEN Encounter END) as '3case'
FROM Table 1
```

---

```
SELECT    
    COUNT( CASE 
           WHEN DischargeDate > '20130609' and DischargeDate < '20140101' THEN Encounter    
           WHEN DischargeDate > '20130509' and DischargeDate < '20131201' THEN Encounter    
           WHEN DischargeDate > '20130409' and DischargeDate < '20131101' THEN Encounter  )
    END AS 'CaseValues'  
    FROM Table 1
```

Can you explain differences between the above code? How do the results vary? What if I change the count to SUM?

I want to the result some thing like this.
  Date Range 
         (DischargeDate > '20130609' and DischargeDate < '20140101') i will call it as 1
     DischargeDate > '20130509' and DischargeDate < '20131201' i will call it  as 2
         DischargeDate > '20130409' and DischargeDate < '20131101' i will call it as 3
 And i want the count of Encounters for each of the above.

```
 Result like :
 EncounterCount     Date
 30                  1
 45                  2
 20                  3
```

Comment: One query produces 3 columns. The other produces only one. Is that enough of a difference for you? Also, `CASE` is an *expression* (something that produces a value), not a *statement*.

Comment: ya the column output is different. But i am worried about the result. Are the result values the same. I did check them by executing they gave me the same result. But i was not sure sure about other differences between. So just wanted to get my self cleared.

Comment: The column output IS the result.  Do you mean, the same number of records?

Comment: Yes column output is the result. But in terms of final calculation done by  Count(case 1 case 2 case 3) same as count(case 1) Count(case2) count(case3) ?  I am not worried about the number of columns or rows it generate

Comment: You are counting the total not null records in table1, the evaluation of the case is irrelevant (if not null)

Comment: Given that the ranges specified are non-exclusive (e.g. a `DischargeDate` of `20130910` will count towards all of `1case`, `2case` and `3case`, but will only be counted once by the second query), I'd say no.

Answer (score 2):

The first statement will return a result set with 1 row and 3 columns:

1. The `count()` of `Encounter` when `DischargeDate` is between 9th June and 31st December 2013
2. The `count()` of `Encounter` when `DischargeDate` is between 9th May and 30th November 2013
3. The `count()` of `Encounter` when `DischargeDate` is between 9th April and 31st October 2013

Note for each of these dates midnight on the first of the dates is excluded - consider whether you need >= rather than >.

The second select will return a result set with 1 row and *1* column, which is the `count()` of the `Encounter` between 9th April and 31st December 2013 - ie all of the which fall in any of the periods above.

`count()` is the number of non-null values. Assuming that `Encounter` is some form of numeric column, changing `count()` to `sum()` will give you the sum of all the non-null values in the `Encounter` column.

Given the information in the updated question, I would suggest something like:

```
with date_limits (DateLabel, StartedAt, EndedAt)
as
(
     select *
     from (values ('1', cast('20130609' as datetime2), cast('20140101' as datetime2))
                ,('2', cast('20130509' as datetime2), cast('20131201' as datetime2))
                 ,('3', cast('20130409' as datetime2), cast('20131101' as datetime2))
     )  as date_limits_input(DateLabel, StartedAt, EndedAt)
 )
 select dl.DateLabel as [Date], count(Encounter) as EncounterCount
 from date_limits dl
 inner join SomeTable t on t.DischargeDate >= dl.StartedAt and t.DischargeDate < dl.EndedAt
 group by dl.DateLabel
 ;
```

Of course rather than the hard-coded values in the CTE (the `with` expression before the main `select`) you could use a table or some way of generating the dates.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much. very wel explained. Appreciate. I have another small doubt...   Say if i want to see the different dates as well in the table. Say if i mark    DischargeDate > '20130509' and DischargeDate < '20131201' As 1 and so on .. Please see below...

Comment: SELECT    
    COUNT( CASE 
           WHEN DischargeDate > '20130609' and DischargeDate < '20140101' THEN Encounter    
           WHEN DischargeDate > '20130509' and DischargeDate < '20131201' THEN Encounter    
           WHEN DischargeDate > '20130409' and DischargeDate < '20131101' THEN Encounter  )
    END AS 'CaseValues'

Comment: CASE WHEN DischargeDate > '20130609' and DischargeDate < '20140101' THEN 1
  WHEN DischargeDate > '20130509' and DischargeDate < '20131201' THEN 2  
           WHEN DischargeDate > '20130409' and DischargeDate < '20131101' THEN 3   
   END as 'DateNumbers'
    FROM Table 1

Comment: What happens now. How will  this we evaluated.. ?

Comment: @user2919277 1) Don't try to put multi-line code into comments, it doesn't work, either 2) edit and append it to your original question, or 3) as a new question.

Comment: I have updated my question .. Can you please explain me how to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

The query answers the question for itself. The first query is an individual count of each case statement. So you will have 3 columns in the result of that query.

The second query is a count of all the case statements' result set and will result in a result set of just 1 column and 1 row.

It depends what you are trying to achieve but if the requirement is flexible, this can be easily done with a having condition as well.

Updated answer for the question

```
create #temp (Encounter int, Date int)
insert into #temp

select count (*) , '1'
from Mytable
where DischargeDate > '20130609' and DischargeDate < '20140101'

union all

select count (*) , '2'
from Mytable
where DischargeDate > '20130509' and DischargeDate < '20131201'

union all

select count (*) , '3'
from Mytable
where DischargeDate > '20130409' and DischargeDate < '20131101'

select * from #temp

drop table #temp
```

Answer (score 1):

They will trivially produce different results, because the three expressions in the first query use overlapping date ranges - and so the same row might be counted multiple times. Whereas in the second query, each row can only possibly be counted once.

Consider 3 rows:

```
DischargeDate, Encounter
20130901     , 1
20130410     , 1
20131231     , 1
```

The first query will return:

```
2,      1,       2
```

And the second query will return:

```
3
```

I cannot reconcile those with any concept of equality that I'm commonly familiar with.

Comment: @user2919277 - rather than posting more and more things like this in the comments, maybe you could *edit* your question and add a) sample data, and b) expected results. That's bound to be more productive than chipping away at it in a piecemeal fashion in the comments. You can also *format* these (using the `{}` button) rather than the flat text of comments.

Comment: I have updated my question .. Can you please explain me how to achieve this